# C# Запись массива в оперативную память и его извлечение

Tags: c#

Есть код, который обращается к файлу xml, извлекает из него данные в массив f01x и обрабатывает этот массив.  Код привязан к Ексель через ДНА. Создана функция, в которой находится ряд аргументов. 
Функция работает прекрасно, но очень медленно.
Проблема заключается в том, что если нужно использовать функцию 1500 раз (в разных ячейках и с разной периодичностью), то огромная часть времени (совокупно 30+ минут) занимает именно подключение к файлу xml (на диске C).

Идея, которая пришла мне в голову, - это один раз прочитать файл xml в массив и этот массив f01x оставить в оперативной памяти, a в дальнейшем, при запуске этой же функции их другой ячейки Эксель (скажем, через 5 минут, после первого запуска), проверять, если аргументы функции равны некоторым ячейкам в массиве, то массив f01x получаем из оперативной памяти ПК (если его не затрет чистильщик), минуя чтение из файла С:\01.xml в массив, а если аргументы функции не равны некоторым ячейкам массива, то массив f01x заполняется из файла xml.

То, что я хотела бы реализовать, должно выглядеть следующим образом:

1. Получаем все аргументы функции.
2. Проверяем, есть ли массив f01x в ОЗУ.
3. Если аргумент функции "Дата" равен определенной ячейке массива то берем массив из ОЗУ, в противном случае, массив заполняем из файла xml.

Изначально, я хочу разобраться с оперативной памятью и в случае, когда массив там находится, брать его из ОЗУ, если его там нет, читать его из xml. Позже, буду допиливать сравнение аргументов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Может у кого-то есть похожие примеры, поделитесь пожалуйста. Нужно чтобы именно массив f01X остался на выходе (заполнен либо из файла, если происходит первый вызов функции, либо из ОЗУ, если функция уже вызывалась ранее (5-10-20 минут назад)).
Помогите, пожалуйста.

После некоторых дискуссий родился вот такой простенький код:

```
namespace C_Sharp
{
    public class Ground
    {
        // Создаю приватное поле в классе Ground
        private string[,] f01x;

        // Создаю конструктор класса с параметрами и в конструкторе заполняю поле из файла
        public Ground(DateTime data, string ekv)
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNodeList xmlnode;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\01.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DATA");
            string[,] f01x = new string[xmlnode.Count, 11];
            f01x[2, 5] = xmlnode[2].ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText.Trim();
        }
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Hello", IsVolatile = true)]
        public static string func01(
    [ExcelArgument(Name = "Дата", Description = "День месяца")]
            DateTime data,
    [ExcelArgument(Name = "Капитал", Description = "Эквити")]
            string ekv)
        {
            // !!!! Так ругается компилятор 
            // !!!! Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект

            return f01x[2, 5];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну сделайте `f01X` приветным полем класса и проверяйте, если оно не инициализировано - то читаем его из файла, если инициализировано - то ничего не делаем.

Comment: Когда массив отработан и выведено определенное значение "return x;" код завершит свою работу. Функция естественно тоже завершит работу. И вот хотелось бы, чтобы при вызове функции повторно, мы уже не читали файл 01.xml в массив f01x, а получили массив f01x из оперативной памяти. Возможно ли вообще это сделать в С# ?

Comment: конечно, функция может отработает, но класс с его поле то останется в памяти

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что нам необходимо вывести все это в отдельный класс, передать в этот класс некоторые аргументы функции и в этом отдельном классе вернуть массив return f01x; ?

Comment: у вас метод уже в каком то классе находится. Надо вам его выводить куда то или нет я не могу знать, я не в курсе организации кода в вашем проекте

Comment: Немного подправила топик, добавила в него полученный код. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. При компиляции компилятор выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект". Не удается её побороть :)

Comment: ну всё верно, вы не можете использовать поля экземпляра в статических методах

Comment: Так, а что нужно подправить?

Comment: ну тут много вариантов. 1) убрать статик `public string func01(...)` 2) добавить статик `private static string[,] f01x;`, 3) Прокинуть экземпляр класса `public static string func01(Ground item, .... ){item.f01x = ...}`. Я не особо могу советовать, вы ведь не уточтяете, как вы вообще этот класс используете.

Comment: То, что вы реализуете, является частным случаем паттерна Одиночка. Есть множество способов его реализации. Посмотрите, например, эту статью: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton). При реализации синглтона обычно напирают на потокобезопасность, но вам она может быть не нужна. Берите либо первый способ, либо последний - с Lazy. И вообще ознакомьтесь с ленивостью - идеально для вашего случая.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша функция должна находится в каком-либо классе ибо это C#.

Сделайте следующее:

В этом классе (как подсказал @tym32167) создайте приватное поле. Создайте конструктор класс с параметрами и в конструкторе заполняйте поле из файла.

После вы сможете вызывать методы класса и пользоваться этой переменной. Если методы не будут статическими, то Вам даже не придется проверять поле на null, полсе создания объекта поле будет уже заполнено посредством конструктора.

Пока у Вас есть ссылка на экземпляр класса, GC не тронет ни класс ни поле (т.к. есть ссылка).

Если функция в main, то я бы посоветовал вытащить все это в отдельный класс.

Дополнение после обновления топика

Как Вам уже посоветовали в комментариях (@tym32167) у Вас несколько вариантов:

1) убрать static у функции

```
public string func01(...)
```

тогда вызов будет такой

```
Ground ground = new Ground(...);
...
string temp = ground.func01(...);
```

2) изменить класс на static или только поле на static, но для этого придется менять код конструктора и поправлять сам класс

Судя по описанной Вами задаче, я бы предпочел 1 вариант.

Comment: Спасибо. Кое-что понятно. С конструкторами как таковыми практики не было. Попробую разобраться, дополнить код.

Comment: пишите в личку/телеграм/сюда - постараюсь подсказать если что-то непонятно

Comment: Немного подправила топик, добавила в него полученный код. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. При компиляции компилятор выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект". Уже ночь, а я все сижу с кодом, пытаясь понять как же сослаться на массив в конструкторе.